# Erro com BD mysql

Tags: php, mysql, banco-de-dados

Estou com um erro no meu bd que não consigo corrigir já utilizei o comando CHECK TABLE com a função EXTENDED e ele diz que não possui erros nas tabelas.

o problema é o seguinte:

fiz algumas alterações no meu sistema em php/mysql sendo elas inclusão de novos campos no formulário e consequente novos campos nas tabelas que são utilizadas nesse formulário.

os novos campos nas tabelas criei manualmente pois elas já possuíam dados e não podia perder, até ai normal fiz os testes e tudo funcionou corretamente.

ai fiz as mesmas alterações em produção, criei os campos nas tabelas e coloquei as paginas alteradas na pasta de produção.

a partir dai começou a dor de cabeça, as alterações que foram feitas não são executadas corretamente em produção, pensei que era um problema no cód. mas não era.

apaguei as tabelas de teste e joguei os dados de produção em teste e deu o mesmo problema de produção.

voltei os dados que estavam nas tabelas de teste e o problema deixa de ocorrer.

já comparei as duas tabelas e elas estão exatamente iguais em relação aos campos(nome, tipo, atributos etc)

ou seja devo ter algum registro que pode estar causando esse problema, só que nessa tabela tem mais de 16.000 linhas.

algum ideia de como corrigir esse problema?

me ajudem por favor já ta tirando meu sono a dias esse problema.

ele não grava os dados nesses novos campos, e no formulário de insert ele possui algumas funções em javascript que em prod não funciona mas em teste funciona, como por exemplo, verificar o saldo disponível do produto, o calculo de valor unitario x desconto, valor unitario com desconto x quantidade, etc

Comment: as alterações que foram feitas não são executadas corretamente em produção, dá para exemplificar o que seria `executada corretamente` e o que seria `executada incorretamente`?

Comment: Tente dar exemplo, a pergunta está muito ampla

Comment: ele não grava os dados nesses novos campos, e no formulário de insert ele possui algumas funções em javascript que em prod não funciona mas em teste funciona, como por exemplo, verificar o saldo disponível do produto, o calculo de valor unitario x desconto, valor unitario com desconto x quantidade, etc